# Issue with updating Realm objects

Tags: ios, xcode, swift2, realm

I have two `Realm` model classes

```
class ModelA: Object {
    let id = RealmOptional<Int>()
    dynamic var name: String!
    // some other variables that are also String! type
}

class ModelB: Object {
    let id = RealmOptional<Int>()
    let models = List<ModelA>()
    // other variables
}
```

And I have some `JSON` object which contains data for that models. I create `ModelB` instance then populate it with `ModelA` instances list the following way:

```
let json: JSON = ... // get it from somewhere, then use SwiftyJSON
let myModelB = ModelB()
myModelB.id.value = json["id"].object as? Int
// set other properties
let modelsA = json["models"].map { ModelA(value: $0.1.object) }
myModelB.models.appendContentsOf(modelsA)
```

The reason why I am using different approaches here is that propery names in `JSON` doesn't match to my property names for `ModelB` but for `ModelA` it is ok.
Somewhere later I use `realm.add(objects, update: true)` (inside `realm.write`) and that leads to the following exception:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key (null).'

According to the [documentation](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest):

> If your model class includes a primary key, you can have Realm intelligently update or add objects based off of their primary key values using Realm().add(_:update:).

so both `ModelA` and `ModelB` has `primaryKey()` function and I believe that should work but it is not.

Furthermore, I removed `update` parameter in the call and added call to the `realm.deleteAll()` before adding new objects (both in `write` callback). In that case I get the following exception:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Can't set primary key property 'id' to existing value 'xxxxxxx'.

Additionally if I try to go through the call stack, Xcode crashes. It also crashes if I try to inspect any `Realm` object in the debugger. I already have installed `Realm` Xcode plugin but nothing changes. I cannot understand what is going wrong here and why I get so strange behavior. Could someone tell me where is my mistake please?

Comment: can you show the code you used to create the realm objects you want to add as well as the modelA itself? Looks like there might be a problem there.

Comment: @BabyAzerty sure, edited my question. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I start project from scratch, base on [example project](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/blob/master/examples/ios/swift-2.1.1/Simple/AppDelegate.swift). So I finished with:

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

// Dog model
class Dog: Object {
    dynamic var name = ""
    dynamic var age = 0
    dynamic var owner: Person? // Properties can be optional

    override class func primaryKey() -> String? { return "name" }
}

// Person model
class Person: Object {
    dynamic var name = ""
    let dogs = List<Dog>()

    override class func primaryKey() -> String? { return "name" }
}

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        do {
            try NSFileManager.defaultManager().removeItemAtPath(Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.path!)
        } catch {}

        let dogRexJSON: AnyObject = ["name": "Rex", "age" : 20]
        let dogLuckyJSON: AnyObject = ["name": "Lucky", "age" : 25]
        var somePerson = Person(value: ["name" : "Shurik", "dogs" : [dogRexJSON]])


        // Realms are used to group data together
        let realm = try! Realm() // Create realm pointing to default file

        // Save your object
        realm.beginWrite()
        realm.add(somePerson)
        try! realm.commitWrite()

        somePerson = Person(value: ["name" : "Shurik", "dogs" : [dogRexJSON, dogLuckyJSON]])
        try! realm.write { () -> Void in
            realm.add([somePerson], update: true)
            return
        }

        let val = realm.objectForPrimaryKey(Dog.self, key: "Lucky")
        print(val!.name) // as expected log >> Lucky

        return true
    }
}
```

Seems all works fine.

Comment: The reason was using `RealmOptional<Int>` as a primary key, but I made it optional only due to `Swift` limitations: I don't think it is a good idea to assign `id` at compile time and overriding `init` doesn't support by Realm yet. But actual value always non-nil. Thanks, I found the reason but still looking for better workaround with primary key

Comment: This issue has been fixed with Realm 1.1.0: https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/3671